# scala readCsvFile behaviour

Tags: apache-flink

I´m using flink to load a csv file to a dataset of pojos, defined through a scala case class, using readCsvFile method, and I have a problem that i cannot solve.
When in the csv there is a record with some format error in any of its fields it is discarded, and I assume that the only way to keep those records is to type them all as String and do the validations myself.
The problem is that if the last field after the delimiter is empty, the record is discarded  by default, I think because it is considered as not having the expected number of fields it should, and it is not possible to handle this record error, while if the empty value if in any of the previous fields there is no problem.

Example
field1|field2|field3
a||c
a|b|

In this example, first record is returned by readCsvFile method but not the second.

Is this behaviour right? and there is any walk around to get the record?
Thanks

Comment: Read, [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example][1] and edit your Question accordingly.

  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Case classes and tuples in Flink do not support null values. Therefore, `a||c` is invalid if the empty field is not a String. I recommend to use the `RowCsvInputFormat` in this case. It supports nulls and generic rows can be converted to any other class in a following map operator.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, as you say, if the field is a String, the record should be valid even if it is null, and this doesn't happen when the null value is in the last field. The behaviour is different depending on the position.

I will try also with RowCsvInputFormat as you recommend.
Thanks